# Is there a way to make a <div> scale properly in a Wordpress theme like Semplice?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes

beginner to HTML and CSS here. I am trying to customize my website that runs on the Semplice wordpress theme. I saw a cool effect on Codepen that allowed you to hover 2 images over each other in CSS. I was able to create my own shape and get the code to work on my theme. I do this by adding a 'code module' which from what I understand just makes a / for the code to run.

The code runs fine, and I was able to add the custom CSS through the theme as well. The problem sits in scaling: As soon as I make the browser width smaller there is a massive gap between the divs (I repeat this code three to four times, I want to use them as project covers) whereas other objects scale perfectly with the theme. I feel like I'm missing a simple padding or margin option here, but everything I tried from margin to padding breaks with scaling. The theme comes with its own internal padding options as well, but they seem to break. I've tried adding margin-bottom and -top to the CSS, with % and pixels but both to no avail.

I understand that there is probably something in the theme here that breaks this code or stops it from being used properly, but I was hoping that something could be added like the !important to stop the code from breaking and/or play nice with the theme.

The HTML used in the DIV:

```
<div class="main" style="height: 100%">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/hMJn55T.jpg" alt="" id="img-1">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/gyjAnHr.jpg" alt="">

</div>
```

The CSS, entered through the theme:

```
}
.main{
    display:inline-block !important;
    margin-bottom:10px !important;
    margin-top:10px !important;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute !important;
}
.main img{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.main h6{
    position:absolute;
    display:inline;
    margin-top: -5%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}
.main #img-1:hover{
    z-index: 99;

  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 95% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
          clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 95% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
    transition-duration: 800ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
}
.main #img-1{
    z-index:10;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 35% 0%, 15% 100%, 0% 100%);
          clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 35% 0%, 15% 100%, 0% 100%);
    transition-duration: 450ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease;

}
```

This is my first post, I tried to be concise but if there is stuff missing or unclear let me know and I'll add more information! :)

The scaling between space can be seen in these pictures: 
[Image: As they should be, before resizing the browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dffye.png)
[Image: Too far apart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzGD8.png)

Update: This is the section as it is in the theme, complete with generated divs by the theme.

```
<section id="section_bbyngcjvd" class="content-block" data-column-mode-sm="single" data-column-mode-xs="single">

                    <div class="container">
                    <div id="row_yobohwqkk" class="row"><div id="column_iht59fpyu" class="column" data-xl-width="12">
                <div class="content-wrapper">

            <div id="content_pozj163h8" class="column-content" data-module="code">

            <div class="is-content ce-code">
                    <div class="main" style="height: 100%">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/hMJn55T.jpg" alt="" id="img-1">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/gyjAnHr.jpg" alt="">

</div>
            </div>

            </div>

                </div>
            </div></div>
                    </div>
                </section>
```

Comment: Do you mean you try to add multiple instances of `<div class="main"...`

Comment: Yes, right now I have 3 'code boxes' within the theme that all use the above html code.

Comment: So you should give the html of the whole container including the 3 blocks or a link to the page for us to test

Comment: I can't release the site, but I'll try and get the code without any references to the projects. I'll get back to you.

Comment: @gael would the updated information be sufficient? I can go deeper in the source, if you want. Taking this out of the site with inspect mode.

Comment: sorry I can't reproduce your bug because it only displays 2 images and your bug seems to happen when there are 4